# Apache mod-rewrite redirect without changing url with parameters

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, system-administration

Below is my configuartion it's redirecting from detailsPage.html to detailsPage.php with parameters but url is changing from detailsPage.html to detailsPage.php can someone help in regard this how to redirect without changing URL

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
LogLevel alert rewrite:trace3
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^/detailsPage.html$ http://exmaple.com/detailsPage.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA,NC]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/detailsPage.html$ http://exmaple.com/detailsPage.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA,NC]
> ```

You need to *remove* the scheme + hostname from the *substitution* string. By including an absolute URL, Apache will implicitly trigger a 302 external redirect, as opposed to an internal rewrite.

You also need to remove `%{QUERY_STRING}` frommthe *substitution* string and the `QSA` flag on the `RewriteRule`, otherwise this will double up any query string on the requested URL. The query string is passed through by default, so there is nothing you need to do in this regard (unless you were merging two different query strings).

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^/detailsPage\.html$ /detailsPage.php [L,NC]
```

I would also question the use of the `NC` flag? Do you specifically need a case-insensitive match, as this potentially creates a duplicate content issue.

NB: Despite your question tagged `.htaccess`, I assume these directives must be directly in your server config or `<VirtualHost>` container? As this won't work in `.htaccess` as written.

Comment: Do you have other directives in your config (`.htaccess` etc.)? This directive by itself won't "redirect" like that, so maybe you have a conflict with other directives? Also, make sure you are not seeing a cached response - clear your browser cache. Presumably you have restarted Apache after making changes to the server config? Where exactly are you using these directives?

Comment: https://example.com/detailsPage.html?id=753300005  
if i try to post this url image in facebook preview of product is not showing how to resolve this issue

Comment: This has nothing to do with how the request is made, whether that is via Facebook, Twitter or direct from the user. If you are only having a problem with FB then that is another issue... OG tags, FB cache?